# Install firefox on CentOS 5.11

Tags: centos

I want to install firefox in centos 5.11.

When I type **yum install firefox** in terminal, I get the following images:
[image]

Is this yum command installing the firefox? 
Am I doing wrong? Is there any other way to install firefox?

Answer (score 0):

No, the install is not currently happening. To keep proper track, only one program can do software package related tasks at one time, in this case, it's probably the widget that occasionally tells you that you have new updates to install looking for updates in the background. Just wait a few minutes and try again, I guess.